# Why when I shrink my splitPane a grey area appears?

Tags: javafx, fxml, splitpane

I have a problem with my fxml interface.
When I try to reduce a specific part of my application, a grey area covers it.

An example in image will be more speaking:

[image: bug demo]

I've tried quite a few things (by modifying parameters of the different components) but the white zone is still there.

Do you have any idea what my problem is?

The code (example):

MainApp.java

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

    loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/test.fxml"));
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

    Controller controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setMainApp(this);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Controller.java

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

  MainApp mainApp;

  @FXML
  Label label;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    label.setText("Hello");
  }

  public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
  }
}
```

test.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane"
    maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
    minHeight="250.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="519.0" prefWidth="921.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="application.view.Controller">
    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.49439102564102566"
            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
            prefHeight="799.0" prefWidth="1250.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="400.0" minWidth="400.0"
                    prefHeight="511.0" prefWidth="467.0" rotate="0.0" />
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"
                    prefHeight="797.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                    <children>
                        <SplitPane layoutX="17.0" layoutY="7.0"
                            orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="797.0" prefWidth="346.0"
                            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <items>
                                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="108.0"
                                    minWidth="447.0" prefHeight="108.0" prefWidth="447.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5248796147672552"
                                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity"
                                            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="112.0" prefWidth="442.0"
                                            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                                            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <items>
                                                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0"
                                                    minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="313.0" />
                                                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0"
                                                    minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="87.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="223.0"
                                                            prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="Test !">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font size="29.0" />
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                            </items>
                                        </SplitPane>
                                    </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                            </items>
                        </SplitPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note: I made this interface with the help of Gluon's SceneBuilder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't link code. Create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem and post it in the question.

Comment: And as you do not understand what happens with the UI, I suggest you to use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) in order to understand what is this grey pane. (it is actually one of your numerous AnchorPane).

Comment: I update my question with an example @James_D.

Comment: Your problem is due to some of the min/preferred values you have set on some of your `Panes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SceneBuilder` if I click on the root `SplitPane` and slide it's divider to the right, I get this picture below. This means that at some point your min values on the highlighted `AnchorPane` is greater than it's parent's current width.

[image]

I basically set most of the later `AnchorPanes'` preferred width to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE` and the highlighted `AnchorPane's` min width to `USE_PRE_SIZE` and it's preferred width to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE`. Here is the code I used to fix the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="250.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="519.0" prefWidth="921.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.view.Controller">
    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.49836779107725787" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="799.0" prefWidth="1250.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="400.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="511.0" prefWidth="467.0" rotate="0.0" />
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="797.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                    <children>
                        <SplitPane layoutX="17.0" layoutY="7.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="797.0" prefWidth="346.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <items>
                                <AnchorPane>
                                    <children>
                                        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5248796147672552" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <items>
                                                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" />
                                                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="87.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="223.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="Test !">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font size="29.0" />
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                            </items>
                                        </SplitPane>
                                    </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                            </items>
                        </SplitPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```